# How to call Java/Kotlin GCP Cloud Functions from Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-functions

I have written a http function in kotlin. It is working fine when tested from GCP. Few lines from the same are :

```
class WinnerDeclaration : HttpFunction {
   override fun service(request: HttpRequest?, response: HttpResponse?) {
   //code ...
   }
}
```

After referring to https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function , I wrote this code :

```
private val cloudFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
val data = hashMapOf("uid" to uid)
cloudFunctions
  .getHttpsCallable("WinnerDeclaration")
  .call(data)
  .addOnSuccessListener {
    //code ...
  }.addOnFailureListener {
    it.printStackTrace()
  }
```

But I am always getting this exception :  `com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: NOT_FOUND`

Comment: If you are familiar with HTTP requests you can use volley or retrofit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onCall` protocol used by [callable Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) is only implemented for the Node.js/Firebase Functions SDK. There is no implementation for any other of the server-side libraries that Google Cloud Functions supports.

So if you want to use callable Cloud Functions written in Java/Kotlin, you will have to implement the server-side version of the [`onCall` protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) yourself.